# Spawn background process from ncat

Tags: netcat

How can `ncat` be used to spawn a process in the background? For example:

```
ncat -lp 2342 -c "setsid sleep 5 &"
```

As I understand, `setsid` and `&` will make the process run in the background but `ncat` does not close until `sleep` finishes. I can forcefully close `ncat` and `sleep` will still run. How can I make `ncat` close immediately while still having `sleep` run in the background?

Comment: Do you want ncat to close (exit) immediately after one connection?
Or could you explain in more detail what you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Indeed, the connection currently just hangs, until sleep returns.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I figured out that I could use [daemon](http://libslack.org/daemon) to get the functionality I was looking for.

```
ncat -lp 2342 -c "daemon sleep 5"
```